# Can I use special char as delimiter for split_to_array function in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a string field where it is a key-value pair, and using Ctrl-A (\u0001) as a delimiter, how can I use split_to_array to tokenize it as an array?

Comment: Have you tried “split_to_array(<col>,chr(1))”?

Answer (score 0):

From Bill, “split_to_array(,chr(1))”